# Java.nio. Can I get a number of bytes available for writing in the send buffer of the TCP socket?

Tags: java, sockets, buffer, nio

We use java.nio and channels in the non-blocking mode. We know that there is a notification about "writability" of the channel (and underlying TCP socket) via selector and its SelectionKey.OP_READ option, but we need to get an exact number of bytes available for writing to the send buffer of specific socket at the moment. Is it possible and what is the simplest way to do this?

Thank You for Your answers!

Comment: Why not just try to write all of your data, and observe the value returned by the `write` method?

Comment: Well, we don't go this way because of two reasons: 1. Don't want to additionally load perhaps already loaded channel. 2. In this case there is a possibility to eventually get an inconsistent data packet on the receiving side (partially received).